# What VPS provider gives many IPs on a single instance?

Tags: vps

I need to setup an off-site duplicate instance of a critical application that requires many IP addresses (say, between 20 and 30). What options are there? I did a bit of research to find out the maximum allowed number of IP addresses that some providers apply:

- Amazon EC2: 1 IP
- Gandi: 4 IP
- Linode: unlimited (needs custom quote)
- ServInt: unlimited
- TurboVPS: unlimited

Are there other choices out there?

Comment: Is IPv4 a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Rackspaces's Cloud offering will as well. Though I left them for Linode which would be my suggestion of the ones I'm familiar with.

Comment: This answer gave me the opportunity to better discover Linode and I'm very interested in their service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think http://vps.net have a limit for public IPs, but they will charge £1 per month per IP.

Answer (score 0):

Most providers don't limit in the literal sense. They give you 1 free one and expect you to pay for more. To add onto what Growse said most providers charge 1 USD or Pound per IP per month on the IPv4 front, IPv6 they are a lot less strict and will most likely assign you a /48

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at Amazon again, they do allow multiple public IP's per instance:

http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/07/06/multiple-ip-addresses-for-amazon-ec2-instances-in-amazon-vpc/

> The number of IP addresses that you can assign varies by instance
>   type. Small instances can accommodate up to 8 IP addresses (across 2
>   elastic network interfaces) whereas High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large
>   and Cluster Computer Eight Extra Large instances can be assigned up to
>   240 IP addresses (across 8 elastic network interfaces). For more
>   information about IP address and elastic network interface limits, go
>   to Instance Families and Types in the Amazon EC2 User Guide.